# How to set column title for JTable?

Tags: netbeans

We can easily drag and drop `JTable` in netbeans but I can't see any options in the properties to change the column title in netbeans.

Comment: Yet another great reason to learn **Java** rather then the editor used to create the program.

Comment: If coding is the only way then this is will still be the stone age.

Comment: If an IDE could do the work of a programmer, we would not need programmers. The shortcuts provided by an IDE like Netbeans can be of great use to an experienced programmer. But *first* you need to understand how to program. As it is, the IDE is not serving you, you are serving it. Good luck with that.

Comment: @M.Sanjay, An IDE is great to help compile, debug etc. But you are much better at logically designing the classes and implementing structured code that is easy to maintain. The code that is generated from one IDE will not maintainable (except for manual changes) in another IDE if you ever need to switch.

Answer (score 1):

Try the documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

This is one of the suggested ways:

```
// The table in SimpleTableDemo.java declares the column names in a String array:

String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
                        "Last Name",
                        "Sport",
                        "# of Years",
                        "Vegetarian"};

// Its data is initialized and stored in a two-dimensional Object array:

Object[][] data = {
    {"Kathy", "Smith",
     "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
    {"John", "Doe",
     "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
    {"Sue", "Black",
     "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
    {"Jane", "White",
     "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
    {"Joe", "Brown",
     "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
};

// Then the Table is constructed using these data and columnNames:

JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
```